# In phpMyAdmin 4.x how to revert browsing as PARTIAL instead of FULL TEXT without clicking the FT GUI toggle?

Tags: user-interface, debugging, phpmyadmin

On a particular database table, after clicking the FT button in the browse interface in phpMyAdmin, now it shows an error 500 whenever I try to browse this table. Therefore, I cannot go back and revert the listing to partial text instead of full text and so, I cannot browse this table ever again in the state it is now.

Is there a place I can hack the full text setting OFF for a given table?

N.B.: If it matters, phpMyAdmin version is 4.8.3

Fortunately, I have tried to rename the table by going to its structure under the Operations tab and now I can browse the RENAMED table as partial text again. The problem is that this table is linked to a web app's PHP files, so I'd rather find a solution that allows the old table name to stick.

And yes, I have tried to dump the whole table and reimport it.  Same thing.  It looks like the full text setting is stored linked to the table name somewhere in the schema, but I couldn't find where this setting is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that setting is stored in a browser cookie; phpMyAdmin's cookies begin with `pma` so deleting any 'pma' browser cookies should reset that sort of setting to the default.

Comment: YUP! You won.  In my case, there were "pmaUser-1" and "phpMyAdminTABLE168100179173" cookies which, after a quick deletion, threw me out of phpMyAdmin (logged out) and back onto the login page and then everything was functional again (not FULL TEXT and so, not throwing an error 500!) THANKS :)